# Need Help in subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of a finite group $G$ such that $|H|>\sqrt{|G|}$ and $|K| > \sqrt{|G|}$.
Show that $|H \cap K| >1$

Comment: Do you know a formula for $|HK|$?

Comment: yes...how to use it?

Comment: Well, the formula contains $|H|$, $|K|$ and $|H \cap K|$. Use $|HK| \le |G|$ and the inequalities you were given to get a contradiction.

Comment: can you help??Let A and B be two subgroup of a group G. If |A| = p , a prime integer, then show that either A $\bigcap$ B = {e} or A is the subset of B

Comment: Did you solve the previous question? If yes, post the solution as an answer.

Comment: |H|> $\sqrt{|G|}$ and |K| > $\sqrt{|G|}$.    and we know |HK|< |G|. Again ${|H||K|\over|H\bigcap K}$ < |G|. Thus |H $\bigcap$K| >1

Comment: i cant post it in answer i only have 6 reputation

Answer (score 3):

Let $f: H \times K \to G$ be defined by

$$f(h,k)=hk$$

As the domain has more elements than the codomain, the function cannot be 1 to 1.

Thus you can find some elements $h_1,h_2 \in H k_1, k_2 \in K$ so that $(h_1,k_1) \neq (h_2, k_2)$ and

$$h_1k_1=h_2k_2 $$

Then

$$h_2^{-1}h_1=k_2k_1^{-1}$$